# VLOOKUP Excel returns #N/A for my boss, but not for me

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-external-data

I got tasked to take over some statistics for management at my company. These statistics are placed on a server that anyone from management has access to and me. We are generating a monthly report based on other reports that are placed on the same server.

Here come the problem:
The values are generated automatically based on a VLOOKUP formula, which is just checking if the data from the other files have a certain value. When you open the report, you get a prompt if you want to update the external links. For me, no matter what I pick, I get no #N/A values. However, when my boss tries to open the same report, no matter what he picks(either update links or not), he always gets #N/A on the cells.

Because of the contract that I signed, I cannot show you any code, however, I can tell you what I have tried:

- At first, I thought that my boss has lost (somehow) some permissions with the external files. But this is not the case, we tested every file and he can access all of them, even being marked as an administrator in some cases.
- Secondly, I checked the report from the current month with one from two months ago (which works for him, no #N/A here) and went through all of the formulas. No luck here either, all the formulas are all the same except the external file name which was changing (I have done this step with the help of Spreadsheet Compare).
- Third, I thought that maybe some macro would be running in the background (even if that makes no sense because these are .xlsx files). No luck here either, there is no VBA code written in any of the sheets of the workbook.

I got no ideas left. He has all the permissions, even more than I do, there is no difference between an old report which works just fine, and this one that is stuck, and there are no running macros. Any ideas?

Edit:
I can give you a sample of the formula, but will replace the actual path with a fake one since I cannot show this proper code:

```
=VLOOKUP(look_up_value, 'O:\fakepath\[file.xlsx]Report'!$C:$AZ, MATCH('Lookup Data'!$B$3, 'O:\fakepath\[file2.xlsx]Report'!$5:$5, 0) - 2, FALSE)
```

Also, I might also add details that were asked below here:

- The language settings and DateTime format is the same both me and my boss
- Both excel files have the same version, including the same display language
- The mapping of the external files is the same for both of us, since they are on a server and we both have the drive letter for the server "O"

Comment: I don't see how any of the things you've checked could affect vlookup in this way. Vlookup shows #NA when the data is not found. So it isn't. What you are telling it to find is not there. You may think it is, but it isn't. Check you data.

Comment: Did you consider firing your boss ?   :-D

Comment: Yes, I do see your point GSerg, but the data is there! If I open the file I get the data, however, if my boss does, he does not and I cannot really get why it happens.

Comment: @CosminLeonte "I see a 1" and "Excel sees a 1" are very different, because Excel does not think `"1"` and `1` are the same.

Comment: Wow! That would drive me insane. Can he log into your machine (if you're in the same office) and see if that's the issue? Another troubleshooting thought: Create a blank workbook and write a cell formula to simply get a specific cell value from file.xlsx, then repeat for file2.xlsx, and send it to him. If it's specific to one file, or another, you'll know. If both work, your problem isn't that you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

No definitive answer since question does not have enough details nor sample formulas, but some ideas:

- are the 2 client machines with the same language settings (windows regional settings) ? that may impact dates and other factors
- are the versions of Excel identical ? (including language)
- external data: if here are external links, do the 2 client machines have the same drive mapping ? (could be P: on yours and R: at your boss pc)
- EDIT: same rights to source folder ?

Comment: Hello, yes both client machines have the same language settings and date formats. Yes, both versions of Excel are identical, with the same common language (English). Yes, the mapping is the same, for both of us the drive letter is "O".

Comment: Response for edit: Yes, the same right to the source folder.